# Mongodb (mongoose) I can't remove sub element from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a league of legends tournament website for a friend, and for each tournament (stored in a database with mongodb) has a list of "premades" of players that want to play the tournament.

I'm using the mongoose module on node.js to manage my database

Here is my model :

```
const tournamentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim: true
    },
    beginningDate: Date,
    endingDate: Date,
    creatorName: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    maxPlayers:Number,
    maxPlayersPerTeam:Number,
    playersList:Array,
    waitingPlayers:Array,
    needLoggin:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    description:String
});
```

For exemple, "playersList" will be :

```
playersList:[
{
  name:"group1",
  players:[
    {
      name:"player1",
      elo:"rank on the game"
    },
    {
      name:"player2",
      elo:"rank on the game"
    }
  ]
},
{
  name:"group2",
  players:[
    {
      name:"player3",
      elo:"rank on the game"
    },
    {
      name:"player4",
      elo:"rank on the game"
    }
  ]
}

]
```

And I'm trying to find how to remove the

```
{
  name:"player4",
  elo:"rank on the game"
}
```

in the group 2 for exemple. I tried to use splice() like if it was a normal array, it updated the object but did nothing in the database. I also tried the tournament.update and it returned an error and I couldn't see what was my mistake...

```
var collection = Rtournament.players;
Rtournament.updateOne({'players.players.name':collection[i].players[j].name},{$pull:{'players.$.players':{'name':name}}},()=>{});
```

So I would like to know a simple way to remove it (as I'm sure my code was really wrong)

Thanks a lot to help me and sorry for my awful english

Comment: What is the error you get? Please show your entire statement.

Comment: I removed this part of the code some hours ago because I couldn't find how to make it work, but the error was 

"Cannot create field 'name' in element (my array)" and myarray was my test array I created from the same model I give in my exemple

Comment: You provide neither your code nor the error message - how can you expect any help from others?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new here and I'm doing my best to be clear ;(
I just want to know how to remove the player4 as I'm sure anyways my code was bad and I wasn't using the update method properly...

Comment: ```
Rtournament.updateOne({'players.players.name':collection[i].players[j].name},{$pull:{'players.$.players':{'name':name}}},()=>{});
```
With collection : "var collection = Rtournament.players;"

Comment: Use the [`$pull operator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) for achieving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to pull the players according to your group. You will have to pass group name and players name.

```
db.collection.update({
  $and: [
    {
      name: "group2"
    },
    {
      "players.name": "player4"
    }
  ]
},
{
  $pull: {
    players: {
      name: "player4"
    }
  }
})
```

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/HEusd_OBO1F

Here is standalone script to test, let me know if it works
Start the mongodb in shell then run node repro.js in terminal

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tournamentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim: true
    },
    beginningDate: Date,
    endingDate: Date,
    creatorName: {
        type:String,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    maxPlayers:Number,
    maxPlayersPerTeam:Number,
    players:Array,
    waitingPlayers:Array,
    needLoggin:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    description:String
});


run().catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

    const TournamentModel = mongoose.model('tournament', tournamentSchema);
    await TournamentModel.insertMany([
        {
          name:"group1",
          players:[
            {
              name:"player1",
              elo:"rank on the game"
            },
            {
              name:"player2",
              elo:"rank on the game"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name:"group2",
          players:[
            {
              name:"player3",
              elo:"rank on the game"
            },
            {
              name:"player4",
              elo:"rank on the game"
            }
          ]
        }
        
        ])
    await TournamentModel.updateOne({
        $and: [
          {
            name: "group2"
          },
          {
            "players.name": "player4"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        $pull: {
          players: {
            name: "player4"
          }
        }
     });
    const result = await TournamentModel.find({}).lean()
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result), 'result')
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. I copied your code and added an argument to db.collection.update ((error)=>{console.log(error)}) to print any error, and the code didn't work and the error printed is null

Comment: I added standalone script for you test and can you reproduce your error with it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you took to help me, works well, when I copied your code I did a mistake when replacing the name of the player... I tested your standalone script and it works well